# ElasticSearch group by aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question regarding the requirement in elastic-search.
I have following documents in my index.

```
{
    "name":"a1",
    "userId": 1,
    "tag":"tag1"
},

{
    "name":"abc",
    "userId":1,
    "tag":"tag2"
},

{
    "name":"a2",
    "userId":2,
    "tag":"tag1"
},

{
    "name":"abc2",
    "userId":2,
    "tag":"tag2"
},

{
    "name":"abc3",
    "userId":2,
    "tag":"tag3"
}
```

Now if my query is to fetch me all the documents for the userID who has tag values as `"tag1"` AND `"tag3"` i.e. in this case documents returned are

```
{
    "name":"a2",
    "userId":2,
    "tag":"tag1"
}
{
    "name":"abc3",
    "userId":2,
    "tag":"tag3"
}
```

so in this case document containing tag values as `"tag1"` but for userId `1` will not be returned as for that userID we do not have document for `"tag3"`.

I was checking on nested bucket aggregation however I was stuck. So can you please suggest what elastic query would be required for this.